How to receive money transfer or payment into CC instead of bank?
I am trying to reroute a payment (or money transfer) from someone directly to my CC (that has a balance enough to absorb the payment), bypassing depositing it into a bank account. Like, someone owes me money and I owe money to someone else (CC), why not have that someone pay directly into my CC account. Is there a way to do it bypassing a bank account? Like a money transfer service that will redeem the account balance to a CC account and not into a bank account.

As commented here - location matters as different countries have different rules.

@mhoran_psprep: There doesn't seem to be an answer on the referenced question.  I think the answer was "not a common feature, and recommending specific services would be out of scope if we did know of one. Stores can issue credits to cards, but presumably you aren't willing to pay for a business account just for this purpose. And outside of stylistic elegance there really wouldn't be much point to it. "

it does not because it does not have an answer -- i thought that other question was getting closed

Another copy of the same question here

If snail mail and paper checks are not too old fashioned and the payer lives in the same country as you, have the payer write a check made out to the credit card issuer and let them mail it to you. Combine this check with a payment stub from your current credit card bill and mail it in as a payment.
Credit card companies don't care who wrote the check. That's what keeps the sugar in "sugar daddy". They also don't care if you overpay and end up with a credit balance, so having a balance due that can "absorb" a payment is not an issue.
Doing it all online? You would have to give your full credit card account number and have the payer use any payment service. That's too risky, of course, unless the payer is a member of your household who could easily get your credit card number by other means.

This is the best way. Once upon a time everybody did this.

@DJClayworth where? Paying with checks was never a thing my home country, it's just not an option that existed (and still doesn't).

In the UK and a few decades back. But sometimes old methods haven't been stopped. Worth asking.
